# Why does adding a printf cause the explosion of the data segment size?

Tags: c, embedded

I am working on a RISCV processor (AIRISC), 32 bits, with support for F-extensions.
The problem is that I noticed that trying to print the values of a statically allocated array with a `printf`, the data segment becomes huge and the program does not run.

The simple piece of code I add to the end of the program (so outside all the for loops and other things) is as follows:

```
    for (int j = 0; j < 64; j++) {
        for (int k = 0; k < 4; k++) {
            printf("%.18f\n", final_conv[j][k]);
        }
    }
```

`final_conv` is defined as `float final_conv[64][4] = {{0}};` 
I compile the whole program with the command:

`riscv32-unknown-elf-gcc -march=rv32i -mabi=ilp32 -Os -Wall -ffunction-sections -fdata-sections -nostartfiles -Wl,--gc-sections -lm -lc -lgcc -lc -g`

and the output is this:

```
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/12.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: warning: main.elf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
Memory utilization:
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  66129  978088      60 1044277   fef35 main.elf
```

if I try to run the program with gdb (`load main.elf` followed by `monitor resume`), nothing happens.

By removing the print with `printf`, the code is compiled with the following output and it is executed by the processor.

```
/opt/riscv/lib/gcc/riscv32-unknown-elf/12.2.0/../../../../riscv32-unknown-elf/bin/ld: warning: main.elf has a LOAD segment with RWX permissions
Memory utilization:
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
  55529    2472      60   58061    e2cd main.elf
```

Is it normal ? Is there a possibility to reduce such data memory utilization ?

**UPDATE**

I tried to obtain the size of functions and static objects using

`$ nm --print-size --size-sort --radix=d main.elf`

obtaining the following output for the version that doesn't print

```
2147492824 00000002 T __malloc_lock
2147492826 00000002 T __malloc_unlock
2147489974 00000002 T __sfp_lock_acquire
2147489976 00000002 T __sfp_lock_release
2147541712 00000004 B errno
2147484292 00000004 T _exit
2147525348 00000004 T _getpid_r
2147541696 00000004 b heap.0
2147541644 00000004 D _impure_ptr
2147541704 00000004 B __malloc_max_sbrked_mem
2147541700 00000004 B __malloc_max_total_mem
2147541648 00000004 D __malloc_sbrk_base
2147541708 00000004 B __malloc_top_pad
2147541652 00000004 D __malloc_trim_threshold
2147489206 00000006 T __errno
2147510732 00000006 T _localeconv_r
2147510738 00000006 T __locale_mb_cur_max
2147484296 00000008 T _close
2147484344 00000008 T _getpid
2147493228 00000008 T __sclose
2147489966 00000008 T __sinit
2147488992 00000008 T __umodsi3
2147489648 00000010 T _cleanup_r
2147485692 00000012 T uart_send_char
2147525166 00000014 T abort
2147520472 00000014 T __sprint_r
2147537136 00000016 r blanks.1
2147538428 00000016 r blanks.1
2147538824 00000016 r blanks.1
2147484384 00000016 T _kill
2147484692 00000016 T timer_set_time
2147484824 00000016 T uart_isRxEmpty
2147484808 00000016 T uart_isTxFull
2147537120 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147538412 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147538808 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147511596 00000018 T _Bfree
2147537840 00000020 r eone
2147537860 00000020 r ezero
2147484052 00000020 T interrupt_handler
2147484708 00000024 T timer_get_time
2147524652 00000030 T _fputwc_r
2147524186 00000032 T __ascii_wctomb
2147484352 00000032 T _isatty
2147537284 00000034 r bmask
2147484072 00000036 T exception_handler
2147484400 00000036 T _lseek
2147489028 00000036 T __modsi3
2147484580 00000036 T _sbrk
2147489106 00000040 T __ashldi3
2147484304 00000040 T _fstat
2147489066 00000040 T __lshrdi3
2147541656 00000040 B __malloc_current_mallinfo
2147492828 00000042 T printf
2147524448 00000044 T fiprintf
2147488948 00000044 T __hidden___udivsi3
2147488948 00000044 T __udivsi3
2147489596 00000052 T _fflush_r
2147484900 00000052 T uart_readByte
2147501278 00000054 T _close_r
2147524740 00000054 T _isatty_r
2147492960 00000054 T _sbrk_r
2147493014 00000056 T __sread
2147524682 00000058 T _fstat_r
2147525290 00000058 T _kill_r
2147489146 00000060 T __clzsi2
2147502304 00000060 t eshdn1
2147502364 00000060 t eshup1
2147510744 00000060 T _lseek_r
2147511614 00000060 T _read_r
2147484840 00000060 T uart_writeByte
2147500998 00000060 T _write_r
2147524218 00000062 T __assert_func
2147489978 00000062 T fputc
2147511076 00000064 T __ascii_mbtowc
2147525098 00000068 T _wcrtomb_r
2147512776 00000072 T sprintf
2147510658 00000074 T _ldcheck
2147493154 00000074 T __sseek
2147484732 00000076 T uart_init
2147484616 00000076 T _write
2147484952 00000080 T uart_writeData
2147493070 00000084 T __swrite
2147488940 00000088 T __divsi3
2147492870 00000090 T _putc_r
2147493236 00000100 T strlen
2147511494 00000102 T _Balloc
2147502424 00000104 t m16m
2147525180 00000110 T raise
2147490800 00000116 T _fwalk_reent
2147512848 00000120 T strcpy
2147512968 00000124 T strncpy
2147512650 00000126 T frexp
2147502528 00000140 t emovo.constprop.0
2147503252 00000142 t emovi
2147511140 00000144 T memchr
2147484436 00000144 T _read
2147500608 00000150 t __sbprintf
2147524036 00000150 t __sbprintf
2147520320 00000152 t __sprint_r.part.0
2147483896 00000156 T main
2147524492 00000160 T __fputwc
2147524280 00000168 T _calloc_r
2147492656 00000168 T memset
2147501332 00000174 T _fclose_r
2147484108 00000184 T __trap_entry
2147488748 00000190 T __extendsfdf2
2147490040 00000204 T _malloc_trim_r
2147534236 00000210 T __floatsitf
2147511284 00000210 T memmove
2147501058 00000220 T __swsetup_r
2147503394 00000232 t ecmp
2147525352 00000234 T __eqtf2
2147525352 00000234 T __netf2
2147500758 00000240 T __swbuf_r
2147504522 00000244 t eiremain
2147504766 00000250 t e113toe.isra.0
2147536280 00000256 R __clz_tab
2147538904 00000257 R _ctype_
2147537320 00000260 r emtens
2147537580 00000260 r etens
2147502668 00000270 t enormlz
2147510804 00000272 T __smakebuf_r
2147525586 00000280 T __getf2
2147525586 00000280 T __gttf2
2147525866 00000280 T __letf2
2147525866 00000280 T __lttf2
2147488462 00000286 T __floatundisf
2147533946 00000290 T __fixtfsi
2147524794 00000304 T __ssprint_r
2147489658 00000308 t __sinit.part.0
2147502938 00000314 t eshift.part.0
2147492330 00000326 T memcpy
2147541280 00000364 D __global_locale
2147489212 00000384 T __sflush_r
2147534446 00000400 T __extenddftf2
2147490244 00000556 T _free_r
2147485032 00000660 t number
2147501506 00000798 T __sfvwrite_r
2147503626 00000896 t emdnorm
2147506076 00000924 t emul
2147487532 00000930 T __divsf3
2147511674 00000976 T _realloc_r
2147540248 00001032 D __malloc_av_
2147505016 00001060 t ediv
2147534846 00001062 T __trunctfdf2
2147539184 00001064 d impure_data
2147490916 00001414 T _malloc_r
2147485704 00001828 T ee_printf
2147526146 00003272 T __multf3
2147520486 00003550 T _vfiprintf_r
2147507000 00003658 T _ldtoa_r
2147529418 00004528 T __subtf3
2147513092 00007228 T _svfprintf_r
2147493336 00007272 T _vfprintf_r
```

and the following for the one that uses a lot of data segment

```
2147503572 00000002 T __malloc_lock
2147503574 00000002 T __malloc_unlock
2147500722 00000002 T __sfp_lock_acquire
2147500724 00000002 T __sfp_lock_release
2148528104 00000004 B errno
2147492192 00000004 T _exit
2147536104 00000004 T _getpid_r
2148528088 00000004 b heap.0
2148528036 00000004 D _impure_ptr
2148528096 00000004 B __malloc_max_sbrked_mem
2148528092 00000004 B __malloc_max_total_mem
2148528040 00000004 D __malloc_sbrk_base
2148528100 00000004 B __malloc_top_pad
2148528044 00000004 D __malloc_trim_threshold
2147499954 00000006 T __errno
2147521484 00000006 T _localeconv_r
2147521490 00000006 T __locale_mb_cur_max
2147492196 00000008 T _close
2147492244 00000008 T _getpid
2147503976 00000008 T __sclose
2147500714 00000008 T __sinit
2147499740 00000008 T __umodsi3
2147500396 00000010 T _cleanup_r
2147493592 00000012 T uart_send_char
2147535922 00000014 T abort
2147547900 00000016 r blanks.1
2147549192 00000016 r blanks.1
2147549588 00000016 r blanks.1
2147492284 00000016 T _kill
2147531224 00000016 T __sprint_r
2147492592 00000016 T timer_set_time
2147492724 00000016 T uart_isRxEmpty
2147492708 00000016 T uart_isTxFull
2147547884 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147549176 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147549572 00000016 r zeroes.0
2147522348 00000018 T _Bfree
2147548604 00000020 r eone
2147548624 00000020 r ezero
2147491952 00000020 T interrupt_handler
2147492608 00000024 T timer_get_time
2147534940 00000032 T __ascii_wctomb
2147535406 00000032 T _fputwc_r
2147492252 00000032 T _isatty
2147548048 00000034 r bmask
2147491972 00000036 T exception_handler
2147492300 00000036 T _lseek
2147499776 00000036 T __modsi3
2147492480 00000036 T _sbrk
2147499854 00000040 T __ashldi3
2147492204 00000040 T _fstat
2147499814 00000040 T __lshrdi3
2148528048 00000040 B __malloc_current_mallinfo
2147503576 00000042 T printf
2147535202 00000044 T fiprintf
2147499696 00000044 T __hidden___udivsi3
2147499696 00000044 T __udivsi3
2147500344 00000052 T _fflush_r
2147492800 00000052 T uart_readByte
2147512026 00000054 T _close_r
2147535496 00000054 T _isatty_r
2147503708 00000054 T _sbrk_r
2147503762 00000056 T __sread
2147535438 00000058 T _fstat_r
2147536046 00000058 T _kill_r
2147499894 00000060 T __clzsi2
2147513052 00000060 t eshdn1
2147513112 00000060 t eshup1
2147521496 00000060 T _lseek_r
2147522366 00000060 T _read_r
2147492740 00000060 T uart_writeByte
2147511746 00000060 T _write_r
2147534972 00000062 T __assert_func
2147500726 00000062 T fputc
2147521828 00000064 T __ascii_mbtowc
2147535854 00000068 T _wcrtomb_r
2147523528 00000072 T sprintf
2147521410 00000074 T _ldcheck
2147503902 00000074 T __sseek
2147492632 00000076 T uart_init
2147492516 00000076 T _write
2147492852 00000080 T uart_writeData
2147503818 00000084 T __swrite
2147499688 00000088 T __divsi3
2147503618 00000090 T _putc_r
2147503984 00000100 T strlen
2147522246 00000102 T _Balloc
2147513172 00000104 t m16m
2147535936 00000110 T raise
2147501548 00000116 T _fwalk_reent
2147523600 00000120 T strcpy
2147523720 00000124 T strncpy
2147523402 00000126 T frexp
2147513276 00000140 t emovo.constprop.0
2147514002 00000142 t emovi
2147521892 00000144 T memchr
2147492336 00000144 T _read
2147511356 00000150 t __sbprintf
2147534790 00000150 t __sbprintf
2147531072 00000152 t __sprint_r.part.0
2147497986 00000154 T __gesf2
2147497986 00000154 T __gtsf2
2147498140 00000154 T __lesf2
2147498140 00000154 T __ltsf2
2147535246 00000160 T __fputwc
2147535034 00000168 T _calloc_r
2147503404 00000168 T memset
2147512080 00000174 T _fclose_r
2147492008 00000184 T __trap_entry
2147499496 00000190 T __extendsfdf2
2147500788 00000204 T _malloc_trim_r
2147544992 00000210 T __floatsitf
2147522036 00000210 T memmove
2147511806 00000220 T __swsetup_r
2147514144 00000232 t ecmp
2147536108 00000234 T __eqtf2
2147536108 00000234 T __netf2
2147511506 00000240 T __swbuf_r
2147515274 00000244 t eiremain
2147515518 00000250 t e113toe.isra.0
2147547044 00000256 R __clz_tab
2147549668 00000257 R _ctype_
2147548084 00000260 r emtens
2147548344 00000260 r etens
2147513416 00000270 t enormlz
2147521556 00000272 T __smakebuf_r
2147536342 00000280 T __getf2
2147536342 00000280 T __gttf2
2147536622 00000280 T __letf2
2147536622 00000280 T __lttf2
2147499210 00000286 T __floatundisf
2147544702 00000290 T __fixtfsi
2147535550 00000304 T __ssprint_r
2147500406 00000308 t __sinit.part.0
2147513686 00000316 t eshift.part.0
2147503078 00000326 T memcpy
2148527672 00000364 D __global_locale
2148269192 00000384 D enc_0_conv_relu_0_w
2147549960 00000384 D final_conv_w
2147499960 00000384 T __sflush_r
2147545202 00000400 T __extenddftf2
2147500992 00000556 T _free_r
2147492932 00000660 t number
2147550344 00000768 D dec_3_conv_relu_1_w
2148268424 00000768 D enc_0_conv_relu_1_w
2147512254 00000798 T __sfvwrite_r
2147514376 00000898 t emdnorm
2147498294 00000916 T __mulsf3
2147516828 00000924 t emul
2147497052 00000934 T __divsf3
2147522426 00000976 T _realloc_r
2148526640 00001032 D __malloc_av_
2147515768 00001060 t ediv
2147545602 00001062 T __trunctfdf2
2148525576 00001064 d impure_data
2147501664 00001414 T _malloc_r
2147551112 00001536 D dec_3_conv_relu_0_w
2147552648 00001536 D dec_3_up_conv_relu_w
2148266888 00001536 D enc_1_conv_relu_0_w
2147495432 00001620 T __addsf3
2147493604 00001828 T ee_printf
2147554184 00003072 D dec_2_conv_relu_1_w
2148263816 00003072 D enc_1_conv_relu_1_w
2147536902 00003272 T __multf3
2147531240 00003550 T _vfiprintf_r
2147517752 00003658 T _ldtoa_r
2147540174 00004528 T __subtf3
2147557256 00006144 D dec_2_conv_relu_0_w
2147563400 00006144 D dec_2_up_conv_relu_w
2148257672 00006144 D enc_2_conv_relu_0_w
2147523844 00007228 T _svfprintf_r
2147504084 00007272 T _vfprintf_r
2147483896 00008056 T main
2147569544 00012288 D dec_1_conv_relu_1_w
2148245384 00012288 D enc_2_conv_relu_1_w
2147581832 00024576 D dec_1_conv_relu_0_w
2147606408 00024576 D dec_1_up_conv_relu_w
2148220808 00024576 D enc_3_conv_relu_0_w
2147630984 00049152 D dec_0_conv_relu_1_w
2148171656 00049152 D enc_3_conv_relu_1_w
2148073352 00098304 D central_conv_relu_0_w
2147680136 00098304 D dec_0_conv_relu_0_w
2147778440 00098304 D dec_0_up_conv_relu_w
2147876744 00196608 D central_conv_relu_1_w
2148269576 00256000 D test_data
```

It is as if by adding the `printf` all the static array data declared in a couple of header files at the beginning of the program are moved to the data segment.

Comment: Which libc are you compiling against? GNU libc? musl?

Comment: I think the `printf()` call makes the compiler pull the libc, which might be too much for your architecture. Try using a smaller one.

Comment: @Botje it should be glibc

Comment: it causes the linker to add the `printf` code to your program which it otherwise doesn't, but I suppose the question is why `printf` includes so much data?

Comment: Answering that question will require a breakdown of size by symbol, especially the data section.

Comment: I found that the same thing happens if I call the expf() function instead of the printf() within the loops.
Trying a simple piece of test code, working on variables and for loops with the same size, the two functions work correctly, taking up some memory but not as much as in the original program.

Comment: @Botje I tried to add that breakdown, I don't know if it could be useful

Comment: It seems that all these `dec_1_conv_relu_1_w` type things are from your code, is that right? How are they defined? Maybe they were unused before, and therefor discarded by the linker, but now that you are printing some of them, they are being included.

Comment: Functions live in the text segment by default, not the data segment, and `nm` .shows that. Static data lives in the data segment by default, also as `nm` appears to be showing you.  It's unlikely that adding a function call caused any data to *move*, but it may be that adding a function call caused some static objects that that were not being included at all to be included.

Comment: "static array data declared in a couple of header files" is extremely suspicious.  It is rarely appropriate to declare static objects in a header file, and especially not large ones.  Doing so gives you a separate copy of each such object in every translation unit that includes the header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some tests with a simple program and the static array involved in the original one.

It appears that, as said in the comments by @John Bollinger, the compiler/linker is smart enough to understand that if a data item is not used then it is not included in the data segment.

This is what seems to happen in my code, where when *printf* is not called there is no output and then it is useless to include the data, needed to compute *final_conv*, in the data segment.
As a result the final size I have when I call printf is the actual size and the program does not execute because the memory in the FPGA is not sufficient to hold everything.

I don't want to say something silly, however, I believe that the fact that I don't get any error on filling the memory is because there is nothing generating a segmentation fault.